# How to get session variables from php server with Ajax function? (PHP HTML JS Ajax)

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, session

so in my php I have something like this

```
$_SESSION['opened'] = true;
```

But It will not be set to true until user will perform some actions with some other html\php pages

So I need on some Ajax function to be able get this session variable. And some PHP sample of function to get variable in form ready for Ajax to get it.

so I need something to AJAX requesting to an action (to some simple php code) which will return a value from `$_SESSION`.

How to do such thing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simple [jQuery](http://jquery.com) example:

```
var session;
$.ajaxSetup({cache: false})
$.get('getsession.php', function (data) {
    session = data;
});
```

And `getsession.php`:

```
<?php
session_start();
print json_encode($_SESSION);
```

You're not *required* to use jQuery for AJAX, but I highly recommend it.

**Edit:**

In response to:

> I want to be able to tell my JS function what variable I want to get.

You can try this (untested):

```
var session;
$.ajaxSetup({cache: false})
$.get('getsession.php', {requested: 'foo'}, function (data) {
    session = data;
});
```

And the PHP:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_GET['requested'])) {
    // return requested value
    print $_SESSION[$_GET['requested']];
} else {
    // nothing requested, so return all values
    print json_encode($_SESSION);
}
```

Have a look at the [$.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) documentation for a more detailed overview.

Comment: Yes! I love It, but how to get specific session variable? I meen I want to be able to get specific session variable - not all. and I want to be able to tell my JS function what variable I want to get.

Comment: Just pass variable name as request parameter so that PHP knows what to return?

Comment: $.get() will cache the result, which isn't good for sessions. See my answer.

Comment: @Ole see my updated answer to request specific variables. I also updated the code so you can use the handy `$.get` syntax without worrying about it caching.

Comment: Can a file like 'getsession.php' not be a big security issue? You can easily read the whole session and maybe some sensible data is stored in it

Answer (score 3):

PHP File at http://my.host/response.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['opened']))
    echo "true";
?>
```

Then in HTML, Add [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) such as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jQuery-x.y.z.js"></script>
```

Then:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:'/response.php',
            cache:false,
            success:function(data){
                // Do something with the result
                if(data=="true"){
                    $('#mydiv').show();
                }else{
                    $('#mydiv').hide();
                }
            }
        );
     });
</script>
```

And add to `myform.php`:

```
<h1>Some Random HTML</h1>
<div id='mydiv' class="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['opened']) && $_SESSION['opened']) echo "hidden_class";?>">
 ...</div>
```

As this will give a consistent experience to those without JavaScript. You don't have to be showing/hiding a div. You could do anything really.

Comment: You need to call `session_start()` to initialize the session data.

Comment: No, I have it set to auto-start in php.ini :P Don't be so pedantic.

Comment: Hey, if you're going to pick at me for cache issues, I'm going to pick back ;)

Comment: Both of our points were legitimate. I just don't think you should assume someone who is new-ish to PHP to have non-default settings enabled. He's probably on a shared host anyway.

Comment: Alright keep your shirt on. But id rather debug a session not starting than my asynchronous calls being cached!

Comment: I'd rather debug neither, so I'm glad we brought these issues to light before it was too late.